# Manually Painted Vertex Weights don't export to FBX, but auto-weights do

Tags: rigging, export, weight-painting, .fbx, vertex-weights

I'm exporting using the AutoRigPro exporter. In Blender, the weights look fine (the first image). However, After auto-weighting to my rig, I needed to do some manual painting around the wrists to fix deform issues. Then on export to FBX I get the issue you see in the second image.

[image]

Any vertex I painted manually or modified in the slightest with the blur tool doesn't seem to export properly.

I checked and the bone I'm weighting to is the correct one, and is exported. The weights are normalized. There are no more than 4 weights per vertex. Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Removed the link to the source file because I solved the issue.
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing weighting issues when exporting and then importing into Blender, and then just doing a tiny test.  Have you tested a Blender import?  The very first thing I'd do is get rid of the empty armature modifier (you have two on your meshes), which is likely to cause problems.  Your post-armature data transfer on your face is not going to export properly, and you should consider applying that before export if appropriate.  Also consider running a normalize all operation on vertex groups prior to export-- may affect export, but in a way that wouldn't show in Blender.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan it may be because I was using the AutoRigPro exporter rather than the default exporter. This is necessary for me because of naming conventions for UE4. Good catch on the empty armature modifiers, I didn't notice those. AutoRigPro is supposed to have those targeted to the "rig_add" armature.

I went ahead and got those targeted properly and still no dice. I had also run the normalize all operation before posting this question, and that was no luck; but great thought. I also made sure to limit to 4 weights per vertex.

Comment: Ahh and the data transfer is just for custom normals. After modifying normals their smoothing breaks on morphing or skeletal deform. But using a data transfer modifier fixes that in blender. Not a problem on export for me, but if I were transferring some other data I definitely can see where that would be an issue to have it applied after the armature modifier. Great insight

Comment: Yeah, the export function matters, as well as where the actual animation is being displayed ("Autodesk FBX Review") and unfortunately, I have access to neither to test.  If problems can be recreated in import-to-Blender, and/or via out-of-the-box FBX export, you may get more eyes.  Sorry, I missed that you mentioned that weights were already normalized.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to conflicting vertex groups in the ARP exporter. To fix it, I removed vertex groups that didn't match the secondary controller mode for ARP (which were added in a different bind session set to "none"). In my case, I needed to remove the following groups because my current bind is set to "twist:"

-arm_stretch

-forearm_stretch

-arm_twist

-forearm_twist

-thigh_stretch

-thigh_twist

-leg_stretch

-leg_twist